# some properties of $\nu$ measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

For any given function $F$ satisfying the following properties

1. $0\le F(x)\le1,\forall x\in\mathbb R$
2. $F(x)\le F(y),x\le y$
3. $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0,\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$
4. $F$ is continuous from the right.

there exists a probability measure $\nu$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathscr B(\mathbb R))$ satisfying $F(x)=\nu(−\infty, x]$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Moreover, such $\nu$ is unique.

I would like to prove as a consequence that $\nu(-\infty,a)=F(a-)$ and $\nu(a,b]=F(b)-F(a+)$

$$F(a-)=\lim_{x\to a-}\nu(-\infty,x]=\nu(-\infty,a)-\lim_{x\to a-}\nu(x,a)=\nu(-\infty,a)-\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu(a-\frac1 n,a)=\nu(-\infty,a)-\nu(\emptyset)=\nu(-\infty,a)$$
I defined $A_n=(a-\frac1 n,a)$,so conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu(a-\frac1 n,a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu(\cap_n(a-\frac1 n,a))=\nu(\emptyset)=0$$
$$F(b)-F(a+)=\nu(-\infty,b]
-\lim_{x\to a+}\nu(-\infty,x]=\nu(-\infty,a]+\nu(a,b]-\nu(-\infty,a]-\lim_{x\to a+}\nu(a,x]=\nu(a,b]-\nu(a,a]=\nu(a,b]$$
Are my proofs right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic is that $\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}vA_{n}$
if the $A_{n}$ are measurable and disjoint.

On this it can be proved that $A_{n}\uparrow A$ implies $\nu A_{n}\uparrow vA$.

This by setting $B_{1}:=A_{1}$ and $B_{n}:=A_{n}-A_{n-1}$ if $n>1$.
Then: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}vA_{k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}vB_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}vB_{n}=\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\right)=\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=\nu A$$

Application of this: $$F\left(a-\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F\left(a-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\nu\left(-\infty,a-\frac{1}{n}\right]=\nu\left(-\infty,a\right)$$

For $a<b$ we have $\left(-\infty,a\right]\cup\left(a,b\right]=\left(-\infty,b\right]$.

This union is disjoint so that $$F\left(a\right)+\nu\left(a,b\right]=\nu\left(-\infty,a\right]+\nu\left(a,b\right]=\nu\left(-\infty,b\right]=F\left(b\right)$$
That leads to: $$\nu\left(a,b\right]=F\left(b\right)-F\left(a\right)$$

There is no nead to write $F\left(a+\right)$.

Note that condition 4) actually states that $F\left(a+\right)=F\left(a\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see any important difference between your answer and me, so I think my answer is right. I am right?

Comment: Your ways are "unnatural". E.g. you make use of $A_{n}\downarrow\emptyset\Rightarrow\nu A_{n}\downarrow0$. This is
true under the condition that $\nu$ is a finite measure but you do
not mention that. There is no need to make use of that. It can be done more "elementary". Also your way to proof $\nu\left(a,b\right]=F\left(b\right)-F\left(a\right)$ is at least unnatural. Limits are not needed to prove that.

Comment: What is $v$ in your answer?

Comment: It is the Greek "nu", i.e. the probability measure you mention in your answer.

Comment: So $v=\nu$. right?

Comment: Yes, I repaired.